# How to show success and error message on popup without reloading the page in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, popup, message

This is my HTML file:

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="passwordchangeform" class="common_form_style popup_form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/changepassword') }}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" style="width:100%">PÅ¯vodnÃ­ heslo </label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="new_password" style="width:100%">NovÄ› heslo</label>
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                <span class="help-block" style="color:#737373;font-size:14px;float:right;margin-right: 30px;font-weight: 100 !important;">MinimÃ¡lnÄ› 8 znakÅ¯, jedno velkÃ© a malÃ© pÃ­smeno a ÄÃ­slo</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="heslo znovu">PotvrzenÃ­ heslo</label>
                                <input id="password_confirmation" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit-btn text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default chci" style="background:#e94549;">UloÅ¾it</button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" id="success-messages"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function changepassword(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();
    $request_data = $request->All();
    $validator = $this->admin_credential_rules($request_data);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $errors
        ], 422);
    } else {
        $current_password = $user->password;
        if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
            $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);;
            $obj_user->save();

            return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('mujucet')
                ->with("modal_message_success", "Password has been changed successfully");
        } else {
            return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('mujucet')
                ->with("modal_message_danger", "wong old password");           
        }
    }
}
```

I have a form for changing passwords. I can change password but it reloads the page. Somehow I want to display these error and success messages on pop without reloading the page. This is possible with AJAX but I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload your page you surely need to use AJAX.

```
...
<!-- other code goes here. -->
<!-- note that type of the button has changed. and onclick event has assigned. -->

        <div class="submit-btn text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default chci"
                style="background:#e94549;" onclick="submitForm()">
                UloÅ¾it
            </button>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;" id="success-messages"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

 <!-- Alert Dialog -->
 <!-- this alert is used to show succes or error -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="alert_modal" style="margin-top: 150px;">
        <div class="modal-body">

            <h3>Alert</h3>

            <h5 id="alert_message"></h5>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger span2" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    // this function calls when the submit button is pressed.
    function submitForm() {

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ url('/changepassword') }}',
            data: $('#passwordchangeform').serialize(),
            success: response => {

                // set message to the alert box.
                $('#alert_message').text(response.message);
                // show the aalert box.
                $('#alert_modal').modal();
            },
            error: response => {

                $('#alert_message').text(response.message);
                $('#alert_modal').modal();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function changepassword(Request $request)
{
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $errors
        ], 422);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Success'
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

this is an example code of what you can do.
things to note here.

1. this uses `jquery` library. if you haven't included it, include it.
2. in the controller, make sure to always return a `response()`. never redirect.
3. since this question is about asking of `how to do this ?` there are several approaches to this
4. since this is an example code there may be lot of errors. so don't copy and paste the code. try to understand what is going on here and write a code that matches your project.

Comment: hey can we have chat

Comment: are u there please get in touch